# Strict inclusion between two subalgebras

Tags: operator-algebras

Let $E$ be a complex Hilbert space, $\mathcal{L}(E)$ be the algebra of all bounded linear operators on $E$.

For a **positive semidefinite** operator $S$, we consider the following two subalgebras of $\mathcal{L}(E)$:
$$\mathcal{L}_1(E)=\left\{A\in \mathcal{L}(E);\;\exists \,c_1> 0;\;\|SAy\| \leq c_1\|Sy\|,\;\forall\,y\in E\right\},$$
and
$$\mathcal{L}_2(E)=\left\{A\in \mathcal{L}(E);\;\exists \,c_2> 0;\;\|S^{1/2}Ay\| \leq c_2\|S^{1/2}y\|,\;\forall\,y\in E\right\}.$$
We have $\mathcal{L}_1(E)\subseteq \mathcal{L}_2(E)$ and the equality hold if $S$ has a closed range.

> I aim to prove that $\mathcal{L}_1(E)\subsetneq\mathcal{L}_2(E)$.

I try with the following example:
Consider
$$
A= \left[\begin{matrix}0 & 1 \\ &0 & 1 \\ &&\ddots&\ddots\end{matrix}\right],
$$
And $S=\mbox{diag}(0,\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{3},\frac{1}{4},\cdots)$.

By the answer of @mechanodroid in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2577557/example-of-a-positiv-operator-which-is-neither-injective-nor-has-a-closed-range), we deduce that $S$ is neither injective nor has a closed range.

> Could you please help me to show that $A\in \mathcal{L}_2(E)$ but $A\notin \mathcal{L}_1(E)$? Or to find $A$ such that $A\in \mathcal{L}_2(E)$ but $A\notin \mathcal{L}_1(E)$.

Comment: Your proposed $A$ is in both algebras. If your goal is to show that $S$ does not have close range, that can be checked directly.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. My goal is  to show that the inclusion can be strict with suitable choice of a positiv operator $S$ and a bounded linear operator $A$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We need to modify your example a bit. Let $S$ be the diagonal operator on $\ell^2(\Bbb Z)$ given by $Se_n= S(n) e_n$. Let $A$ be the operator given by $A e_n=\sqrt{A(n)}e_{-n}$. $S(n)$ and $A(n)$ are some positive numbers (bounded from above). Then we have

$$\|S^{1/2}Ax\|^2=\sum_{n\in\Bbb Z} S(-n)A(n)\, |x_n|^2, \qquad \|S^{1/2}x\|=\sum_{n\in\Bbb Z} S(n)\,|x_n|^2,\\
\|SAx\|^2=\sum_{n\in\Bbb Z} S(-n)^2A(n)\, |x_n|^2,\qquad \|Sx\|^2=\sum_{n\in\Bbb Z} S(n)^2\,|x_n|^2.$$

Take
$$S(n)=\begin{cases} \frac1{n^2}& n>0\\
 \frac1{|n|}& n<0\\
0&n=0\end{cases}\qquad A(n)= \begin{cases}\frac1n&n>0\\0&\text{else}\end{cases}.$$

Then the top left is equal to
$$\|S^{1/2}Ax\|^2=\sum_{n>0} \frac1{n^2}\,|x_n|^2≤\sum_{n>0}\frac1{n^2}\,|x_n|^2+\sum_{n<0}\frac1{|n|}\,|x_n|^2=\|S^{1/2}x\|^2.$$
Thus $A\in \mathcal L_2$. However We have $\|SA e_n\|^2=1/{n^3}$ for $n>0$ whereas $\|Se_n\|^2=1/n^4$. Thus a constant $C$ so that
$$\|SAe_n\|^2≤C\,\|Se_n\|^2$$
is not possible. This shows that $A$ cannot lie in $\mathcal L_1$.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I have a question: why $S$ hasn't  a closed range?

Comment: The range of $S$ contains all finit linear combinations of $e_n$ with $n\neq0$. The closure must thus contain $(\Bbb Ce_0)^\perp$. But this is not the case. For example $\sum_{n>0}\frac1{n} e_n$ is not in the image.

Comment: Thank you but just I don't understand what do you mean by $(\mathbb{C}e_0)^\perp$ and why the closure must contain $(\mathbb{C}e_0)^\perp$? And tahnk you for your help

Comment: $\Bbb C e_0 = \{ z\,e_0\mid z\in\Bbb C\}$. The image contains $Q=\{e_n\mid n\in\Bbb Z-\{0\}\,\}$, the closure of $\mathrm{span}(Q)$ must thus be contained in the closure of the image. The closure of the above span however is the orthogonal complement of $\Bbb Ce_0$.

Comment: No, I do not agree. Note that if $n>0$ then $Ae_n = \frac1{\sqrt{n}} e_{-n}$ and then $S^{1/2}Ae_n = \frac1{\sqrt n}\frac1{\sqrt n}e_{-n}$.

Comment: Thanks a lot. But I think that $S^{1/2}Ae_n=\frac1{n}\frac1{\sqrt{n}}e_{-n}$. Yes or no? Thank you

Comment: That would be $SAe_n$, not $S^{1/2}Ae_n$.

Comment: But in $S(n)$ you have defined if with $1/{n^2}$

Comment: Remember that $A$ moves the $e_n$ (with $n>0$) to $e_{-n}$, here $S$ acts as $\frac1{|n|}$.